# How to let android app skip a lot of frames?

Tags: android

There is a place in my android app where the hard and long work is going on. But I can't use multithreading in my application (all operations must be done on the main thread). Sometimes an error occurs: *I / Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames.* How to let the app skip more frames?

Comment: Choreographer is not something to be enable or disable. It is the object behind the scene handling your screen refreshing.

Comment: Ok. Then is there a way to let the app skip more frames?

Comment: _all operations must be done on the main thread_ Why ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The message mentioned is not an error, it is an Info message. Your question is not clear. Would you like to "let the app skip more frames" or you want to get rid of such Info messages?..